# Nestjs + sequelize

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs

If I try like:

```
async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
  return await this.userModel.build(createUserDto)
}
```

Get error:

> Argument of type 'CreateUserDto' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'.
> Type 'CreateUserDto' is missing the following properties from type 'User': creationDate, deletionDate, updatedOn, users, and 43 more.

Why it doesn't work like in [this example](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript#build-and-create)?

Comment: Probably there is a few properties missing, try to put the optional parameters with a "?", like this deletionDate?. Otherwise share your Dto and your User class.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.